# How to handle deep recursions that ends with the java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

i got a programm with realy deep recursions, iam sure it has no endless loop. But after short time (1s) i get

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

is there a possibility to increase the time that he trys to end the programm? I would like to run it a few hours if possible ;-)

Comment: if your program is coded to produce `java.lang.StackOverflowError` it is not nice way to extend the duration, rather you could fix that issue

Comment: Replace the recursion by an iteration.

Comment: We need to see some code that produces the StackOverflowError. Also, the full stack trace would be useful to work out what's wrong. And if the recursion is going deep enough to overflow you should probably be working iteratively.

Comment: @JigarJoshi and extending it by a factor of 10,000 isn't practical. ;)

Comment: @James I suspect the stack trace will be around 10,000 deep and the stack trace will only give you the top 1024 levels. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good point, I saw question with error and no code/trace and asked for more info out of habit :P

Comment: How deep your recursion go? Print how deep it goes..

Comment: @James Not reading the error and stack trace properly or not knowing what it means is a common mistake.  However, Java doesn't handle deep recursion as well as some languages (e.g. it doesn't optimise tail recursion) and its stack trace can be next to useless. ;)

Comment: Why are you so sure that you have no endless loop?  Is it possible that you've made a mistake?

Comment: This isn't related to "time taken" at all. If your stack size - which means the number of times you recurse - crosses a certain limit (say 10,000), you will always get the overflow error. Such deep recursion is a bad idea. Use the iterative approach instead, as explained by some of the responses.

Comment: "I am sure it has no endless loop." I am even more sure that it does. The default thread stack in Java is a megabyte on some systems, and you would need a lot more than 10,000 recursions to hit that. Post some code.

Comment: Since i have in some cases a result it is not endless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further the comments about reducing recursion/changing to an iterative pattern, and example may be useful. If we take the factorial function as an example, it can be written recursively (and often is) like this:

```
int recurse(int n){
    if(n = 0) return 1;
    else return n*recurse(n-1);
}
```

however, it could be done iteratively (and therefore avoid producing stack overflows for large n) like this

```
int iterate(int n){

    int ans = 1;
    for(int i = n; i > 0; i--){
        ans *= i;
    }
    return ans;

}
```

It is probably worth doing something similar to your code to avoid the recursion (which is likely the cause of your Error) as it is (almost?) always possible to make recursion iterative

Comment: Thanks a lot james, i had an problem in my iteration thats why the recursion was so high.

Comment: Just for even more clarity for anyone who stumbles on this in future, the point of iteration is to store the result after each step, while recursion can be thought of as writing out a very long function and only doing an = operation once (but with more stack usage)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a bug. You can increase the heap size with `-Xss` but it sounds like you would way want to increase it much larger than the size of your machine.

I suggest you reduce the amount of recursion you are using so it only descends tens of levels if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [this discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t150601-recursion-depth-in-java.html), you can do the following:

- Expand the size of the stack with a run time option (`java -Xss` and `java -Xoss` options)
- Use an optimising compiler to reduce the stack overhead at each layer ([example given](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jet.html))

Also, you can try the -server option on the JDK version of Java.exe, since it handles things a bit differently.

However, it does sound that you might be asking too much and need to find a different approach for the things you are doing.